# Increase RAM on 32-bit Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I work with Windows Server2003(Enterprise Edition, Service Pack 2, 4 GB RAM, 32 bit) and also a Terminal Service installed on virtual machine. WS2003 is 32 bit and the maximum amount of memory that can be supported on WS2003 is 4GB.

Could someone tell me if there is any way to increase memory in WS2003?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You can put as much memory in the machine as you like but 32-Bit OS's will only use 4GB(max) of it. TO use more memory, you need to upgrade the OS to a 64-bit one. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You could try to obtain the source code and rewrite Windows but the easiest way would be to install the 64 bit version. You should also not be running Terminals Services on a VM if you can possibly avoid it, unless of course you enjoy having your users complain.

Comment: Are you guys forgetting about PAE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Server2003(Enterprise Edition, Service Pack 2, 4 GB RAM, 32 bit) Supports up to 32GB of RAM.

At the time of writing, here is the list: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758523%28v=ws.10%29.aspx, and here is the Enterprise Edition specifically:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739866%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Most applications won't be able to take advantage of extra memory: some may understand extra memory -- but actually run worse, and some, like terminal services, will be able to support larger loads with extra memory.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily run more than 4 GB of RAM on Windows 2003 EE through Physical Address Extension.  I have a dozen Terminal Servers with that configuration running anywhere from 6 to 16 GB of RAM.